# flatMap для итератора

Tags: java, java-stream, итераторы

Даны вложенные итераторы. Нужно написать метод, который соберет все элементы данных итераторов в List.

Для преобразование итератора в стрим нужно воспользоваться методом iteratorToStream(). Для решения нужно также использовать методы flatMap() и collect().

мой код:

```
public class FlatIt {
    public static List<Integer> flatten(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToStream(Iterator<T> it) {  
      return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, 0), false)
                .flatMap(it -> StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.ORDERED), 
                false).collect(it.toList())
                .it());
    } }
```

мой тест:

```
public class FlatItTest {

    @Test
    public void whenIt() {
        Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it = List.of(
                List.of(1).iterator(),
                List.of(2, 3).iterator()
        ).iterator();
        assertThat(
                FlatIt.flatten(it),
                is(List.of(1, 2, 3))
        );
    }
}
```

что нужно сделать чтобы код работал правильно?

Comment: 1) Метод `FlatIt.flatten` возвращает пустой новый список, так что трудно ожидать прохождения теста. 
 2) Код метода `iteratorToStream` не вызывается и банально не компилируется из-за путаницы с названием аргумента `it` и какой-то белиберды в части`.collect(it.toList()).it())`

Comment: Спасибо! Понял куда двигаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it = List.of(
                List.of(1, 2, 3).iterator(),
                List.of(4, 5, 6).iterator()
        ).iterator();
        List<Integer> result = flatten(it);
        System.out.println(result);
//        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }

    public static List<Integer> flatten(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iteratorIterator) {
        return iteratorToStream(iteratorIterator).flatMap(Main::iteratorToStream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToStream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED),
                false);
    }
}
```

Comment: нужно код писать в методе iteratorToStream

Comment: Что мешает переименовать метод?

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: метод flatten нельзя изменять. и тест тоже.

Comment: private static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToStream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED),
                false);
    } этот код не проходит тест.

Comment: Что значит не проходит тест, подробнее можно? я скинул рабочий код с тестом, тест можно изменить на тот, который был. Если запустить мой код, то он рабочий. Или вы не можете переформатировать код?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <[1, 2, 3]>
     but: was <[]>
Expected :is <[1, 2, 3]>
Actual   :<[]>

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, хорошее лаконичное решение!

Comment: @Dr.Joe, если не менять метод `flatten` в вашей реализации, всегда будет возвращаться пустой список.

Comment: @Nowhere Man, я понял спасибо!